# Job application questions - are they valid?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

A few of the questions from a quiz in our job application process have been appearing on Stack Overflow - direct copy/paste from the questionnaire. None of the "flag" categories seemed to fit and I wonder if these questions are valid? Should I flag them for removal?

It's not really causing a problem in the job app process - if they need to go to SO for these questions, it'll be pretty obvious at some point in the process - but I feel like they shouldn't be on SO at all.

One of them is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654001/reorder-the-declaration-of-operators-such-the-function-returns-0

Comment: I'm assuming you won't let them access Stack Overflow if/when they are working for you? :)

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#designatedagent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It depends on the question.**

Stack Overflow is not in the business of policing users' actions with regard to other entities like potential employers, so questions shouldn't be flagged for that reason.

However, in the case of that question, it falls into the category of [what not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions **based on actual problems that you face**. *[Emphasis added.]*

That question is not an actual problem, it's a purposely highly contrived problem.

Moreover, it also falls into the category of **Too Localized**:

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

Hopefully your interview questions will never reach the point of being of interest to the internet at large.

All that said, **some interview questions are fine**.  If you ask questions like "[Sorting 1 million 8-digit numbers in 1MB of RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748246/sorting-1-million-8-digit-numbers-in-1mb-of-ram)," on your questionnaire that's a perfectly legitimate question for both an interview and Stack Overflow and should not be removed.

Comment: The key phrase here is **"Stack Overflow is not in the business of policing users' actions with regard to other entities like potential employers..."** We do the same thing with homework questions, I believe. If the question has merit in and of itself, it doesn't matter whether it's homework or not.

Comment: Looks like the main thing is that the questions themselves won't be terribly useful to the wider community - which means they'll get closed, but not necessarily deleted.  Thanks for the clarification

Comment: I don't think we have "Too Localized" any more. Perhaps update this answer?